# Run a Explorer / Folderbrowserdialog with another users permission

Tags: c#, windows, impersonation

I have an application that should be able to run explicit tasks in another users context, so that within the application, a less privileged user is able to do some tasks, he is not allowed to.

I used for this an impersonation and it works fine with the acutal code, but I can not make it work with a Folderbrowser Dialog. I think the browser is executed within the context of the correct user, but uses other windows functions which override the user context.

My code that does not work is:

```
    private void tb_customRoot_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ImpersonationHelper.Impersonate("STARK", VSSFileExplorer.Properties.Settings.Default.FS_User, BASE64.Base64Decode(VSSFileExplorer.Properties.Settings.Default.FS_Password), delegate
            {
                VistaFolderBrowserDialog myFancyFolderDialog = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog();
                DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");

                try
                {
                    rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(VSSFileExplorer.Properties.Settings.Default.CustomRoot);
                }
                catch
                { throw; }

                myFancyFolderDialog.SelectedPath = rootDir.ToString();
                myFancyFolderDialog.ShowDialog();

                tb_customRoot.Text = myFancyFolderDialog.SelectedPath;
            });
    }
```

The problem is, that after opening the browser dialog, windows opens a "Enter network credentials" login prompt. The user should not know this credentials. 
Is there a way to run a Folderbrowserdialog with another users rights?

I also build a function which will generate the correct path from some Tools in the GUI, but I am really interested if this is possible.

Thanks in advance.